# Close jQuery Dialog on Function Call

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

How do I close a jQuery dialog when a function is run? I have so far found solutions to the other way around (running a function after closing the dialog).

Comment: "Close a jQuery dialog when a function is run" and, "bind a function to the close event for the dialog" are the opposite. Which is it?

Comment: The former is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [close](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#method-close) method.

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog( "close" );
```

As the docs state, `close()` "Closes the dialog."

Answer (score 0):

I've had good experience with something more like..

```
$(".selector").clone().dialog("open");

/* Then when you're done with it */
$(".selector").dialog("close").destroy();
```

The important fact being that depending on what DOM objects you're working with, most of them maintain state, and since the underlying code is merely hiding and revealing the div and repositioning it, closing the dialog does not reset the state of the dialog, an intended artifact, though most of the time it's a bit of an annoyance.